# Difference in behaviour using one input file and many input files

Tags: input, foreach

I have noticed difference in behaviour when loading a single file

```
\input{letters/all_letters}
```

and when loading several files using a command

```
\newcommand*{\alphabetF}{%
  a,aa,b,c,d,e,ee,f,g,h,i,ii,j,k,l,m,
  n,o,oo,p,r,s1,s2, t,u,uu,v,w,x,y,yy,th,ae,oe}

\foreach \l in \alphabetF{
  \input{letters/\l.tex}}
```

The difference is in behaviour of thumb index. Thumb index disappears from the last page (of the letter) and appears on the first page of the next letter when the letters start the page. In case the letter starts on the second column, the behaviour is correct.

[image]

```
% THUMB INDEXES
% new counter to hold the current number of the letter to determine the vertical position
\newcounter{letternum}
% newcounter for the sum of all letters to get the right height of a box
\newcounter{lettersum}
\setcounter{lettersum}{34}
% some margin settings
\newlength{\thumbtopmargin}
\setlength{\thumbtopmargin}{\ifshowcrop 3cm\else 1.5cm\fi} %1cm
\newlength{\thumbbottommargin}
\setlength{\thumbbottommargin}{\ifshowcrop 6cm\else 2cm\fi} %2.5cm
% calculate the box height by dividing the page height
\newlength{\thumbheight}
\pgfmathsetlength{\thumbheight}{%
(\paperheight-\thumbtopmargin-\thumbbottommargin)%
/%
\value{lettersum}
}
% box width
\newlength{\thumbwidth}
\setlength{\thumbwidth}{\ifshowcrop 2cm\else 0.5cm\fi} %0.5cm
% style the boxes
\tikzset{
thumb/.style={
   text=white,
   minimum height=\thumbheight,
   text width=\thumbwidth,
   outer sep=0pt,
   font=\sffamily\bfseries,
 }
 }

\def\thumbnew{}
\def\thumbold{}
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\if\relax\thumbnew\relax\xdef\thumbnew{\thumbold}\fi}

\def\ethumbs#1,#2\relax{\if\relax#1\relax\else\eventhumb{#1}\fi%
                        \if\relax#2\relax\else\ethumbs#2\relax\fi%
                        \gdef\thumbnew{}%
                        \gdef\thumbold{#1,}%
}

\def\othumbs#1,#2\relax{\if\relax#1\relax\else\oddthumb{#1}\fi%
                        \if\relax#2\relax\else\othumbs#2\relax\fi%
                        \gdef\thumbold{#1,}%
                        \gdef\thumbnew{}%
}

\newcommand{\drawthumb}[2]{%
  % see pgfmanual.pdf for more information about this part
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [thumb, fill=\BoxColor{#1}, text centered, anchor=north #2]
       at ($(current page.north #2)-%
%            (0,\thumbtopmargin+\value{letternum}*\thumbheight)%
            (0,\thumbtopmargin+#1*\thumbheight)$) {\csname Let#1\endcsname};
   \end{tikzpicture}}
\fi

\newcommand{\oddthumb} [1]{\drawthumb{#1}{west}}
\newcommand{\eventhumb}[1]{\drawthumb{#1}{east}}

\newcommand{\lettergroup}[1]%
  {\refstepcounter{letternum}%
   \expandafter\gdef\csname Let\theletternum\endcsname{#1}%
   \xdef\thumbnew{\theletternum,\thumbnew}%
   \fancyhead[LO]{\phvfamily\bfseries\rightmark%
     \expandafter\ethumbs\thumbnew\relax\relax\relax}%
   \fancyhead[RE]{\phvfamily\bfseries\leftmark%
     \expandafter\othumbs\thumbnew\relax\relax\relax}}
```

Comment: Can you give the community a *small, minimal example* that replicates the result? Create files using [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) and create arbitrary dictionary items using [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\foreach` does its work in groups and this might be the cause for your trouble, because of timing when marks are set or local and global assignments.

Try replacing the `\foreach` with

```
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=\alphabetF\do{\input{letters/\next.tex}}
\makeatother
```

Of course you can bury this into a macro:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\multiinput}[3][.tex]{%
  % #1 (optional) = extension, with leading .
  % #2 = prefix, such as `letters/`
  % #3 = comma separated list of items
  \@for\next:=#3\do{\input{#2/\next#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

and call it like

```
\multiinput{letters/}{\alphabetF}
```

Comment: @chejnik Sorry, a brace was missing

Comment: @chejnik Happy to know! I made a full answer.